# Include a non-rails class into the controller folder

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a class "Dog" in my models directory. It is just a simple ruby program. Does not inherit from active_record. Now I need to create a Dog object but in the controllers folder, in my Users controller.

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You simply make an instance of Dog in the Users controller.

Class in models

```
class Dog

    def hi
        puts "HI"
    end

end
```

Controller

```
class MainController < ApplicationController
  def index
    dog = Dog.new
    dog.hi
  end
end
```

Comment: ok thanks. I havent tried it yet because I didnt know if rails was capable of recognizing the class' file location

Comment: @TestTest But that's where the models are, and you can create those, right?

Comment: yes but those are rails models, so I guess rails knows where they are. my Dog class is not an active record class

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be easier to save the Dog class in /lib/dog.rb and then require that file in the UserController.  This way you you are keeping all of your ActiveRecord classes together and you maintain access to your Dog class.

app/controllers/users_controller.rb

```
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/dog.rb"

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  ...
  # code that uses the Dog class
  ...
end
```